# Are Lebesgue integral definitions equivalent for nonnegative bounded functions on finite support?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

According to Royden's Real Analysis, if $f$ is a bounded measurable function, with $m(E)<\infty$, then the integral is defined as
$$\int_E f = \sup \{\int_E\phi:\phi \text{ simple}, \phi \le f\}$$

On the next chapter, if $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function, the integral is defined as $$\int_E f = \sup \{\int_Eh: 0 \le h \le f \text{ is bounded, measurable, finite support}\}$$

Then if $f$ is a nonnegative, bounded function on a set of $m(E)<\infty$, it only makes sense for the two definitions to be equivalent. However, this is not obvious to me, so I want to show it.

This is what I have so far.
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\int f & = \sup \{\int h: 0 \le h \le f, h \text{ is measurable}\} \\
 & = \sup \{\sup \{ \int \phi: \phi \text{ simple}, \phi \le h\}: 0 \le h \le f, h \text{ is measurable}\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I feel like I'm almost done here. In fact, it looks equal to the first definition because intuitively, it's like the squeeze theorem. But I can't quite express it formally, so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h$ is non-negative and the set $E$ has a finite measure, then $h$ can be approximated **uniformly** on $E$ by non-negative simple functions $\le h$ (from below).

[https://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/spring11/section4.1.pdf](https://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Eheil/6337/spring11/section4.1.pdf)

Suppose you define the integral using the second definition. Then, for any $\varepsilon>0$  there exists $h$, measurable with $0\le h\le f$ such that
$$
\int_E f\le \int_E h+\varepsilon
$$
Now you can approximate $h$ uniformly by a simple functions $g$ on $E$ to conclude that
$$
\int_E h\le \int_E g+\varepsilon
$$
(true because you can choose $|g-h|=h-g\le\varepsilon/m(E))$ and thus you have
$$
\int_E g\le \int_E f\le \int_E g+2\varepsilon
$$
so your function is integrable according to your first definition.